# Android Emulator Softkeyboard not appearing correctly

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation, android-softkeyboard

On my Android Emulator, it Softkeyboard cut at the bottom for some reason. Just wondering if someone know what's the fix for that?

Below is the screenshot describing the issue.

[image]

Comment: I guess the window isn't resizable, is it? :)

Comment: @Axarydax - resizable?

Comment: what about another emulators?

Comment: @RomaBugaian - another emulator?

Comment: @itsaboutcode I mean another emulating another version of android

Comment: @RomaBugaian - I have not checked it as I have created only one machine image.